# Swift3 Mixing Static and Dynamic Cells UItableViewController Seperated by Sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

After I finish reading all the staff about combining static and dynamic cells, I wanted to ask whether or not can I mix them with diffrent sections (grouped).

For exmaple:

Section -1 :7 static cells.

Section -2: dynamic cells.

Section -3: dynamic cells.

Can someone please explain for me and for others how can I do it in a single TableViewController.

Just for note - it's not duplicate thread, the other threads don't deal with sections.

Thanks for the helpers :)

Comment: You table view either contains static cells or dynamic cells, regardless of whether or not sections are used. You will need to write code that returns the appropriate cells for the first section vis the data source methods

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have this arrangement

Section -1 :7 static cells.

Section -2: dynamic cells.

Section -3: dynamic cells.

You will have to create a uitableviewcontroller for static cells, which doesnot allow having multiple tableviews